# Flex 3: Using array item value as an objects name

Tags: apache-flex

If I have a list of items in an array that represent the names of modules:

```
var phaseNames:Array = new Array("directorsPrep", "checkIO", "pickupPhoto", "pickupPhoto", "syncing", "dailies", "pictureEdit", "soundEdit", "soundMix", "colorCorrection", "finishing");
```

and I want to go through each one of these and call a function within each instance of each module, how would I go about doing so.  So far, I have the following:

```
private function changeStartViewDate(numDays:Number):void
{
    startViewDate = rightDate(startViewDate.getMonth(), startViewDate.getDate() + numDays, startViewDate.getFullYear());
    getDateInfo();
    determineCalendarWeek();
    var phaseNames:Array = new Array("directorsPrep", "checkIO", "pickupPhoto", "pickupPhoto", "syncing", "dailies", "pictureEdit", "soundEdit", "soundMix", "colorCorrection", "finishing");

    for (var i:int = 0; i < wholeProject.length; i++)
    {
        wholeProject[i].moveProject(Number((1-2) * numDays));
    }
    for (i = 0; i < phaseNames.length; i++)
    {
        for (var j:int = 0; j < [phaseNames[i]].length; j++)
        {
            [phaseNames[i]].movePhase(Number((-1) * numDays));
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to save it, I get the following error:

> 1084: Syntax Error: expecting identifier before dot.

It's telling me the error is on the following line:

```
[phaseNames[i]].movePhase(Number((-1) * numDays));
```

I tried doing something like the following, but it didn't work:

```
[phaseNames[i].movePhase(Number((-1) * numDays))];
```

The above attempt of trying to figure this out gave me the following error

> 1064: Invalid metadata.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume that:

1. Each value of your phaseNames array references an actual instance of some other class [and not the name of the class]
2. The instance defined in the phaseNames array is a child of the current class.

You should be able to do something like this:

```
var childName = phaseNames[0];
var myChild : myObjectType = this[childName];
// then call function
myChild.doStuff();
```

This approach is not dissimilar to what you have; I'm just doing it in more lines.  I'm also adding the this keyword to access the child.

I bet if you tried this, directly, it would work:

```
this[phaseNames[i]].movePhase(Number((-1) * numDays));
```

I have to wonder why you haven't created an array of all the instances instead of an array of all the variables names that point to the instances.